# How do I export or call method from component in another component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react. Maybe someone can help me.  I have 2 components. getData() in Weather Component should call the method getPoint() from the component PointsOfInterest. How can I do that?

Component 1:

```
import React from 'react';
import  { getPoint, PointsOfInterest } from './PointsOfInterest'

class Weather extends React.Component {
   
    getWeather = async (city) => {

  ...
        }

    }

 getData = async (city) => {
      await this.getWeather(city)
      getPoint(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude); 
    }
render()
{
return ...    }
```

Component 2:

```
export class PointsOfInterest extends React.Component {
state = {nameOfPoints: ''}
fetchToken = async () => {
...
}

getPoint = async (latitude, longitude) => {
  const auth = await this.fetchToken()
...

}
render(){
  return(...)
}
}

export default PointsOfInterest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing PointsOfInterest in weather component, you can have an additional prop ref in PointsOfInterst (as shown below) . By ref you can access the methods of PointsOfInterst in weather component. I have done the code changes below for Weather component

You can do like

```
import React from 'react';
import  { getPoint, PointsOfInterest } from './PointsOfInterest'

class Weather extends React.Component {

constuctor(props){
// Changes made here
this.pointOfIntrst =  React.createRef();

}
   
    getWeather = async (city) => {

  ...
        }

    }

 getData = async (city) => {
      await this.getWeather(city)
   if(this.pointOfIntrst.current) {
          await this.pointOfIntrst.current.getPoint(this.state.latitude, 
       this.state.longitude); 
}
    }
render()
{
<PointsOfInterest ref = {this.pointOfIntrst} .../>
return ...    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I have this error  "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'current' of undefined"

Comment: You need to set the values in constructor also and you can check the values. I have edited the answer

Comment: Sorry, the word constructor was misspelled. But now there is another error 
"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.pointOfIntrst.current.getPoint is not a function"

Comment: You can try to print console.log(this.pointOfIntrst.current), and see for the values. May be you have been doing some mistake there

Comment: what value are you getting for "this.pointOfIntrst.current"

Comment: I have a Obj with props, refs, etc. Thank you,you have helped me a lot